# How to create multiple if statements in JavaScript? (closed)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

[Closed as both answers are working for this example, thanks!]

I'm getting values from a dynamic JSON file (that is getting it's values as an array from a sensor through an ESP8266) and and I'm trying to get a different word for each value of the sensor. But as I'm trying to do it, the conditional evaluates to true to multiple statements.

I need help on conditionals to get the word for each value, for example, if I get '25' as value, I need to get displayed just the word 'sad', not the words 'anxious' or 'happy'. If I get the value '37', I want just 'happy' to be displayed.

Here's the code:

```
if (val0 > 40){
 fill(255,0,0);
 textSize(15);
 text('anxious',width/2-50,70); 

} else if (val0 > 35) {
 fill(255,200,0);
 textSize(15);
 text('happy',width/2-50,70); 

} else if (val0 > 20){
 fill(0,0,255);
 textSize(15);
 text('sad',width/2-50,70); 

} else {
 fill(255);
 textSize(15);
 text('nothing',width/2-50,70); 
}
```

As you can see, I'm completely new on js, so please guide me a little!

Comment: What does your current code do that's undesirable? Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: I can't get past to 'sad' as the condition evaluates true, but I need to have different states, so if I get 40, I can't get 'anxious', because it remains as 'sad' as it's true.

Comment: by introducing an array of the "bounds" (`[(-1), 0, 20, 35, 40 (,very high value)]`) ..and looping over it;

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code as written. Every time this code runs, it will only execute one of those branches (note, however, it will only evaluate the first branch if `val0` is *greater than* 40). There's probably something else going on here if it's truly behaving as you describe or some sort of misunderstanding about control flow. As CertainPerformance said, please provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the conditions wrong in the if statement, Consider number 45, it will satisfy all the 3 conditions namely >40 >35 and >20 and the first condition the code encounters will apply, which is the >40 condition so the code inside that block will be executed. You have to apply the conditions in ranges

```js
if (val0 >= 40){
 fill(255,0,0);
 textSize(15);
 text('anxious',width/2-50,70); 

} else if (val0 >= 35 && val0<40) {
 fill(255,200,0);
 textSize(15);
 text('happy',width/2-50,70); 

} else if (val0 >= 20 && val0<35){
 fill(0,0,255);
 textSize(15);
 text('sad',width/2-50,70); 

} else {
 fill(255);
 textSize(15);
 text('nothing',width/2-50,70); 
}
```

Comment: Multiple `if/else if/else` cannot get hit - guatanteed by the language - once a match is found,  there's no further check.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, but I still feel it's extremely misleading. Placing an `else` after an `if` is sufficient to ensure that only one of the branches is executed. If it it fails the `if (val0 > 40)` condition, you know it is not greater than 40, so you do not also need to check that later. Note also that your range checks are flawed because if `val0 === 40` it will fail the first and second conditions and fall all the way to the `else`.

Comment: placing an else after the if is not sufficient, the OP has different code for a value which is 25(>=20 <35), different for 37(>=35 <40) and different for 45(>40).You just cannot ignore them

Answer (score -1):

you can use more curly braces and tabs to make your if structure more readable.

```
if(condition)
{
//do something
}
else
{
    if(condition)
    {
    //do something
    } 
    else
    {
        if(condition)
        {
        //do something
        } 
    }
}
```

but I do think your particular problem is better suited using a switch statement

*****EDIT******

```
switch (true) {
    case (val >= 40):
       //do something
       break;
    case (val >= 35):
        //do something;
        break;
    case (val >= 25):
        //do something;
        break;
    default:
        //do something;
        break;
}
```